# Why was SendBatch remove from Event Hubs .NET Standard client? Is there a replacement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-eventhub

Until recently the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost library was the easiest way for C# users to interact with Azure EventHubs. On February 2, 2017 a new library, Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, was released replacing the functionality of the EventProcessorHost library.

The ServiceBus library includes a SendBatch functionality which was very useful when sending large amounts of small data. Batches of up to 256kb could be sent. The new library does not include batching functionality.

Am I overlooking something? Why would Microsoft leave out a much used feature. What is the alternative?

More details of the change can be found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-client-reaches-ga/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a

```
Task SendAsync(IEnumerable<EventData> eventDatas);
```

method overload to send a batch of messages. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/EventHubClient.cs).

Comment: Obvious. I should have read the documentation before posting.Thanks.